# How To Send Information To A Specific User With Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

***Hello! First I'll explain what the game does and then what's my issue:***

So I'm making an app where players can play a small game with each other. *First*, they are presented with a table view in which it displays their names. Each name is of a player that has created a game room.

A player then selects a game room to play in (which only allows 2 people) then the game will start. The game uses a variable called 'phase'. This is a reference that I use to store data under in the Firebase Database (code below). In which I call later in the app to get the 'phase' of the current game.

However, when I change the value of the reference, it changes it for everyone in the app. So no matter who you're playing against, if one person changes the value, it takes affect amongst everyone. So, how can I resolve this?

*This is how I store data to the Firebase Database:*

I first create the reference in order to store the data.

```
private lazy var currentPhaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("currentPhase")
private lazy var whoWonCurrentPhaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("whoWonCurrentPhase")
```

Then to get the current phase, I observe it:

private func observerCurrentPhase() {

```
    currentPhase = currentPhaseRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        let phaseData = snapshot.value as! UInt

        self.currentPhase = phaseData

    })
}
```

I understand why this isn't working. It's not working because I'm setting values that are available to everyone.

So, how would I have the reference be different for each user (Example: Player 1's Did is 123456, so the reference would be '123456CurrentPhase')? That way when they're playing the game, it's pulling data from an individualized reference name. But how would I communicate to either user what that is, so that they are both using the same reference?

*Another way to ask it would be*: **How would I set it up to where both users could use *ONE* individualized code to pull data from.**

*Note*: The player that selected the cell to play a game, and the player that actually started the game, are two different ViewControllers/Code files. So I'm not worrying about formatting one controller to work on either end. IE. When you create a game, and select a game, they're sending you to two different controllers.

Thank you for the feedback and let me know if you need any further details or have an questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your games, you can have your database look something like this.

```
{
  games : {
    fbgeneratedId1 : {
      host: userid1,
      client: userid2
      matched: true,
      gameid : fbgeneratedId1,
      WhoWonCurrentPhase: "Bob"
    },
    //case when a client joins the game
    fbgeneratediId2 : {
      host: userid1,
      matched: false,
      gameid:fbgeneratedId2
    }
    //a newly created game with only the host
  }
}
```

So games would be your list of games. A game would be inserted into the list when a host creates a game so something like this:

```
var newGameRef =  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("games").push();
var myGameId = newGameRef.key
//create a new game and store it's ID inside so its easy to access for updates
newGameRef.set({
    host: userid1,
    matched: false,
    gameid: myGameId
});
```

When a host creates a game they must know the key for the game and when the client joins they should know the key as well so that they would only manuipulate the game object to their game alone. So your phase ref becomes:

```
private lazy var whoWonCurrentPhaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("games/"+myGameId+"/whoWonCurrentPhase")
```

You can flag that game as matched so it can be filtered out from the game listings if you wish. Note: myGameId would b one of the fbgeneratedIds

Comment: I'll test this out. I'm currently working on a work around. So, when the player selects the cell, the name of it is stored (each cell name is different). Then when the player goes and create a new reference the name is implemented into it. The player who created the game has the name already and the client gets the name through the cell. Thoughts?

Comment: This sounds like a similiar approach but I'm not too sure what you mean by the word 'cell'.

Comment: Cells are the individual rows in a table view. IE with the name of the player or the name of the room.